# Can't get Django to upload files (UPDATE: SOLVED)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have read many questions, followed the Django docs, googled for answers, and I can't get to upload a file in my Django app.

There is no error, form.cleaned_data shows the file and the other foreign key field, but no upload to media folder and no record in my db.

I can't figure what am I missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#models.py
class ReportFile(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/reports')
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    
        user = get_current_user()
        if user and not user.pk:
            user = None
        if not self.pk:
            self.creado_por = user
###UPDATE: As Iain Shelvington kindly pointed out, I was missing the call to super.
        super(ReportFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



#forms.py
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:                
        model = ReportFile
        fields = ['file','report']
```

This is the view I'm using, based on what I've read

```
#views.py
def CreateFile(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
        print(form.cleaned_data)
#OUTPUT: HTTP POST /file 200 [0.09, 127.0.0.1:59053] 
#        {'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test-image.png (image/png)>, 'report': <Report: 49>}
        return render(request, 'segcom/file_upload.html', {'form': form,})
  else:
    form = FileForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
return render(request, 'segcom/file_upload.html', context)
```

The relevant settings that I know of

```
 #settings.py
# Media Root
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This is the template I'm using

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} File Upload Test {% endblock %} 

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
                <div class="row">
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    <form method = 'post' action="{% url 'file_upload' %}" id="report-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form|crispy}}
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" form="report-form" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
{% block javascripts %}


{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: Firstly, the `ReportFile.save` method doesn't call `super` so it effectively stops instances of the model ever saving to the DB

Comment: You are fast!, and that was it! Thank you very much. I missed it when I copied from another model